# Не работает Mask Input JS

Tags: javascript, html

Подгружаю страницу:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#div-space').empty();
            $('#div-space').load('QWERREWQ').show('low');
```

Но маска не применяется к `input`, полный код:

```
function phisFaceLive() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#div-space').empty();
            $('#div-space').load('QWERREWQ').show('low');

        });
    }
$(function($) {
            $("#phone").mask("+7(999) 99-99-999");
          });
```

Как к подгружаемой форме применить маску?

Comment: сделайте воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Надо маску применять после загрузки разметки. Вызовите `$("#phone").mask("+7(999) 99-99-999");` после `$('#div-space').load('QWERREWQ').show('low')`

Comment: делал, увы не выходило.

Comment: Покажите, как делали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понимаю в чем была проблема, но решил её тем, что подключил JQuery через ссылку:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

Скачал JQuery Mask с другого источника и подключил после:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app/scripts/jquery.mask.js' %}"></script>
```

Прописал событие после подгрузки формы:

```
 function phisFaceLive() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#div-space').empty();
            $('#div-space').load('QWERREWQ', function () {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                                $(function($) {
                    $("input[name='u_phone']").mask("+7(999) 99-99-999");
                });
                    alert('TestCheck');
                });
            }).show('low');

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#phone").mask('+7 (000) 00-00-000');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" id="phone">
```

Comment: Это для стандартной страницы.
А у меня загружается в пустой div форма. 
И на эту форму не применяется маска.

Comment: @Jlovenpk1Life, так предоставьте исходный код в нормально виде